# Why is this causing an 'Index out of range' exception?

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

```
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        char[] delimiters = { ',', '\r', '\n', ' ' };
        string[] content = File.ReadAllText(CSV_File).Split(delimiters);

        int bounds = (content.GetUpperBound(0)); //bounds of this content string is 96
        int i = 1;
        id = new string[(bounds / 4)]; //for example index size = 96 / 4 = 24

        for (i = 0; i <= (bounds / 4); i++)
        {
            int rows = (i * 4); // gets every 4th value
            id[i] = content[rows]; //inserts row 96 into id 24 - fails here
        }
    }
```

Stuck on this for a while now. The exact error is "Index was outside the bounds of the array". I do not know to which index this refers however.

Comment: Please avoid including tags in your question title.

Comment: sorry, does a tag suffice then?

Comment: Yes. Tags are one of the most popular ways for SO users to find relevant questions, so if you feel the need to classify your question for people to find it tags should be the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you accidentally wrote <= instead of <. Remember that array indices go up to the length - 1.

I might recommend cleaning up the code a bit. That's a lot of extra brackets and variables...

```
var delimeters = new[] { ',', '\r', '\n', ' ' };
var content = File.ReadAllText(CSV_File).Split(delimeters);

id = content.Where((n, i) => i % 4 == 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Could you explain the last line to me? I've not been coding long.

Also is it better to create a variable and then assign it a 'new' in most cases?

Comment: If you're new, this might be pretty hard to explain. I'll try :)
The Where function returns all the elements that match the specified condition (or predicate). In this case, it tests where the index of each element is a multiple of four (a multiple of n % n always equals 0). Where returns IEnumerable, so ToArray is needed to cast it back to an array.

Comment: You can find the docs for this function @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx

Comment: Okay cool. What does the % operand do? I think I get everything else (to an extent :D)

Comment: % returns the remainder of a division.
Ex. 8 % 7 = 1

Answer (score 3):

Change the `<=` to `<` in the for loop.

Comment: always the obvious things... much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the content of the file you are actually reading. The code seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

For best coding practices, it would be better to check against `id.Length` in the for loop instead of checking against `bounds / 4`.

With that said, I believe you should be using `<` instead of `<=` in your conditional statement in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe on the last iteration you will get the exception, because on the last iteration you are accessing index `(bounds / 4)`, but the valid range of indexes are `0` to `(bounds / 4 ) - 1`. Basically, you are going one past the end of your array `id`. You need to change the `<=` to a `<` in your loop condition.